# Check if a 64 bit BigInteger contains all non-zero upper 32 bits in Java?

Tags: java, math, bit-manipulation, biginteger, bit

Anyone know how to do this -

Check if a 64 bit BigInteger contains all non-zero upper 32 bits in Java?

Thanks!

Comment: You can also test individual bits with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#testBit(int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
private static final BigInteger MASK = BigInteger.valueOf(0xffffffff)
                                                 .shiftLeft(32);

...

public static boolean top32BitsSet(BigInteger value) {
    return value.and(MASK).equals(MASK);
}
```